# ld: -no_pie and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together error

Tags: ios, xcode7, iphone-4, bitcode

When I try to execute my app from XCode 7 on my iPhone 4 I get the ld error:
ld: -no_pie and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

What is that -no_pie, and how to fix the problem, without of course disabling bitcode?

When I compile for the iPhone 6 simulator, everything goes without this issue altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the Generate position-dependent code configuration to YES in the PROJECT settings, which apparently overrode the configuration in the targets.

Answer (score 0):

no_pie makes clang generate position-independent code AFAICS. try to specify -pie to the linker

see also:
[Can I make clang generate absolute addresses for function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743252/can-i-make-clang-generate-absolute-addresses-for-function-pointers)

Comment: It may be so, thanks. But where do I specify this option? The Other linker flags? Also the post you referred has several possibilities for the option.

Comment: Actually I have report:
'argument unused during compilation: -pie', so that must not be the right spot.

Comment: mhm sorry - seems that wasn't the answer. if it possible at all I don't know

Comment: Well, I would just need instruction about where to put that option, not a big deal indeed.